# Slideshow ou player com MP4 e JPEG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho vários arquivos, alguns mp4 outros jpeg e preciso de uma playlist ou de um slide que passe por esses arquivos sendo que fiquem em um tempo 'x' sobre as imagens e quando chegarem nos vídeos eles executem um autoplay e só passe para o próximo item quando o vídeo chegar ao fim.